# Trying to create a typescript definition for proj4, how to declare anonymous static?

Tags: typescript, proj

The transormer method below should actually be anonymous but that is not allowed in typescript:

```
class Proj {
    static (a, b): {
        forward: (p: Point) => Point;
        inverse: (p: Point) => Point;
    };
    static defs(name: string): any;
    static defs(name: string, def: string): void;
    static transform(from: any, to: any, pt: Point);
    static parse(sr: string): any;
}
```

So how can this be defined such that the following is possible?

```
import proj = require("proj");
proj("EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326").forward([0,0]);
```

Comment: I'm looking through the documentation of `proj4` and I don't see anywhere that `new proj4("some string")` is called. I don't think it's necessary by looking at [the source](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js/blob/master/lib/core.js) either. You can define `proj4` as a function and then create a `proj4` module with the other functions like `defs` and `transform`.

Comment: Removed constructor.  Can you demonstrate?  https://gist.github.com/ca0v/2e3da4ce0c7178f102f1

Comment: Now its, $ npm install --save @types/proj4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like below?
When you declare a function and a Module with the same name (the function needs the be declared before the module or you will get an error) they merge.

Below is the code you had with some small changes (and I removed some functions).

```
interface Item {
    forward: (p: Point) => Point;
    inverse: (p: Point) => Point;
}
function Proj(a, b): Item {
    return null;
}
module Proj {
    export function defs(name: string): any {
        return null
    }
}

Proj.defs("");
Proj(1 ,3).forward(null);
```